# Get a single column values as a flat list in Apache spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Java and Apache spark and trying to figure out how to get values of a single column from a Dataset in spark as a flat list.

```
Dataset<Row> sampleData = sparkSession.read()
                          .....
                          .option("query", "SELECT COLUMN1, column2 from table1")
                          .load();

List<Row> columnsList = sampleData.select("COLUMN1")
    .where(sampleData.col("COLUMN1").isNotNull()).collectAsList();

String result = StringUtils.join(columnsList, ", ");
// Result I am getting is
[15230321], [15306791], [15325784], [15323326], [15288338], [15322001], [15307950], [15298286], [15327223]
// What i want is":
15230321, 15306791......
```

How do I achieve this in spark using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark row can be converted to String by Encoders:

```
    List<String> result = sampleData.select("COLUMN1").as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pasting the answer in Scala. You can convert it into Java as there are online tools available.

Also I am not creating **String result** as the way you specified because it would require creating table and doing the query per your process but I am replicating the problem variable directly using

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row    
val a = List(Row("123"),Row("222"),Row("333"))
```

Printing a is giving me

```
List([123], [222], [333])
```

So apply a simple map operation along with mkString method to flatten the List

```
 a.map(x => x.mkString(","))
```

gives

```
List(123, 222, 333) which I assume is your expectation.
```

Let me know if this sorts out your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. @pasha701's solution worked for me.